# How to implement "import" in a Python-like interpreter?

Tags: python

I am just writing an python interpreter for fun to see how some language features can be implemented.
Now comes to the point of implement "import"....... Do you guys have some ideas about how to do that? What are some potential problems?

Comment: @Daniel I can imagine to access to modules when seeing import and the like. However, this approach might cause some problem in the analysis phrase, where I have to analyze the "external" modules, which can be enormous work. (Yes, not only the interpreter, there are some analysis going on in my work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

[**Importing Python Modules**](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm)

[**Python modules - How do they work**](http://www.mbmproject.com/tbtricks/python_modules.php)

[How does import keyword in python actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094506/how-does-import-keyword-in-python-actually-work)